# Too many arguments passed to Stored Procedure storing image

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am trying to store a JPG image into a `MSSQL Server 2014`.  The image path was being passed into a stored procedure and part of the process within the proc is to store the image into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field (I cannot change schema). My first attempt was within the same proc like this:

```
DECLARE @pictureSql VARCHAR(300)

SET @pictureSql = 'INSERT INTO PictureBinary
(PictureId, BinaryData)
SELECT ' + CAST(@ImgId AS Varchar) +', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + 
@ImgPath1 + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) rs'

EXEC(@pictureSql)
```

Even though the command that came from the `PRINT()` statement executed as expected I ran into problems executing it within the stored proc.  It was a VARCHAR conversion error that nearly caused the laptop to take a flying lesson, but part of the research I was doing suggested breaking this bit out into a separate stored procedure. Without really understanding the logic of the reasoning and in desperation I followed this path.  Same problem.

Then I changed the stored proc to accept the binary data and pass it in via a calling app.  I based it on  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133996/how-to-store-image-in-sql-using-stored-procedure).

(stripped down version)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertImage] @ProductId INT, 
@imagePath NVARCHAR(300), 
@mimeType VARCHAR(40), 
@seoFilename NVARCHAR(300), 
@altTag NVARCHAR(300), 
@titleTag NVARCHAR(300), 
@ImgData VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @Id INTEGER

    SET @imagePath = REPLACE(@imagePath, '''', '''''')
    SET @seoFilename = REPLACE(@seoFilename, '''', '''''')
    SET @altTag = REPLACE(@altTag, '''', '''''')
    SET @titleTag = REPLACE(@titleTag, '''', '''''')

    DECLARE @ImgId INT

    INSERT INTO dbo.Picture
    (MimeType, SeoFilename, AltAttribute, TitleAttribute, IsNew, VirtualPath)
    VALUES (@mimeType, @seoFilename, @altTag, @titleTag, 0, NULL )

    SELECT @ImgId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.PictureBinary (PictureId, BinaryData)   
VALUES (@ProductId, @ImgData)

    INSERT dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping (ProductId, PictureId, DisplayOrder) 
VALUES (@ProductId, @ImgId, 1)

    SELECT @id;
END
```

It is called from another SP like this:

```
DECLARE @childResult INT

EXEC @childResult = dbo.usp_InsertImage  
@ProductId = @ProductID, 
@imagePath  = @ImgPath1, 
@mimeType = 'image/jpeg', 
@seoFilename =  @SeoFilename1, 
@altTag = @ProductName, 
@titleTag = @ProductName, 
@ImgData = @ImgBinary1
```

Have also tried unnamed params:

```
EXEC @childResult = dbo.usp_InsertImage  
@ProductID, 
@ImgPath1, 
N'image/jpeg', 
@SeoFilename1, 
@ProductName, 
@ProductName, 
@ImgBinary1
```

No matter what I try I get the same error:

> Procedure or function usp_InsertImage has too many arguments specified.

I have got to a point where I am not so sure I am even approaching this is the right way, it seems way more irritating than it should be.  Either that or I am being a total plank and missing something obvious, its a 50/50 chance.

This is just dev code but can someone tell me if this approach is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that you are connected to a different database (or different instance) where the definition of the procedure hasn't been updated. Please check your connection strings (and make sure nothing you're using is doing anything like `AttachDbFileName` - which means it is using its own, different copy of the database file). See [this](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178889/61305) for more details.

You can confirm your calling code is *not* connecting to a different database by:

- changing the procedure definition to have *too many* required arguments, and see if the error message changes.
- change the *name* of the procedure, and see if your existing code still finds it.
- create a copy of the procedure, with a different name, and change your code to see if it finds the new object.

Comment: The was some debug code left in a part of the code I hadn't touched where the connection string was being hard set.  I guess knowing your connection strings are correct in the config isn't enough.  Thanks